# What does 我就立刻知道他准是对儿媳干了偷鸡摸狗的勾当 mean? (from 活着, p.3)

Tags: translation

I'm having trouble understanding this:

> 他手指挖着裤管上的泥巴，愤怒地告诉我是他那不孝的儿子，当我再问为何打他时，他支支吾吾说不清楚了，**我就立刻知道他准是对儿媳干了偷鸡摸狗的勾当**。
>   <sub>活着, p.3</sub>

My translation is:

> [With] his finger picking trouser-leg mud, [he] angrily told me that it was his unfilial son, [but] when I next asked him why hit him, he hummed-and-hawed [and] spoke unclearly; I immediately knew he (准是对 ???) [his] daughter-in-law work (?) [in] stealthy, shady business.

**Question**: What does 我就立刻知道他准是对儿媳干了偷鸡摸狗的勾当 mean?

It seems like [准](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%87%86) means allow, but I don't know why 是 nor 对 is used here.  It's possible [干](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B9%B2) may mean "to have sex" here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 我就立刻知道他准是对儿媳干了偷鸡摸狗的勾当.

准 means **surely;definitely**.

是 is used as an adverb:

> （重读， 表示坚决肯定， 含有“的确、实在”的意思）

E.g. 他是不知道 // He certainly doesn't know.

对 is a preposition, meaning **to**. E.g. 你对我做了什么 // What have you done to me.

干 means 做(do).

Over all, the sentence roughly means:

> I immediately knew he surely had done some stealthy, shady business to his daughter-in-law.

P.S. As you suspect, the sentence might invoke some sexual affairs.

Answer (score 3):

他「準」是對 means 他「肯定」是對. The meaning is not「准」(允許).

> 我就立刻知道他準是對兒媳幹了偸鷄摸狗的勾當
>
> *I immediately knew that he did something shady to [pronoun] daughter-in-law.*

Answer (score 3):

I would translate it as

> 他准是对儿媳干了偷鸡摸狗的勾当
>
> He must have done [something] to his daughter in law

The translation should reflect the following:

1. he knew
2. but he was guessing

In the link you provided, there is an example:

> 这人准是她丈夫。
>
> This man must be her husband.

It also used "must" in the translation. I feel that if you use "surely is" or "did" the guessing part is missing. Since you're better in English, maybe you can help me understand this.

Comment: I feel the difference between *"I immediately knew he surely had done"* and *"I immediately knew he must had done"*, if any, is very subtle. But I'm not a native English speaker. I'm glad if anybody can teach me here.

Answer (score 2):

I [then] knew immediately that he must have done something filthy [shady, stealthy, unseemly, etc.] to the daughter-in-law.

我 [就] 知道  立刻 他 准是 干了 偷鸡摸狗的勾当 对 儿媳.

准是 = 一定是. 干 = 做 =  do. No need to connect the latter to its extended meanings.

Answer (score 0):

他手指挖着裤管上的泥巴，
His finger scraping the mud off his trouser leg,
愤怒地告诉我是他那不孝的儿子，
he angrily told me his son is not a good son,
当我再问为何打他时，
when I asked why he hit him,
他支支吾吾说不清楚了，
he mumbled an answer,
我就立刻知道他准是对儿媳干了偷鸡摸狗的勾当。
I immediately knew he must have had sex with his daughter-in-law, (possibly raped her).

Just normal village life!

Comment: The sentence has not directly said that he have had sex with his daughter-in-law.

Comment: No, of course not, that is much too direct for Chinese people! They would never say that! What do you think he did? To what may 勾当 refer?

Comment: It might invoke some sex affair, but not necessarily. It's just something bad which is unspeakable.

Comment: @Pedroski -- any special reason why 不孝, (not fifilal),  is translated as "not a good son"? Could it be that the context of the situation calls for a "circumstantial translation" rather than a direct translation?   As for

Comment: As for 偷鸡摸狗的勾当, in an ordinary context, it may mean to steal or some unlawful activity. However, in the context of the situation in question when a 儿媳, (daughter-in-law) is involved and also using 干了 and 勾当  (which are normally used to describe some action which is not "morally good", especially 勾, "to hook" ), then I would say that sex, possibly non-consensual, was meant to have taken place or allegedly so.

Comment: I would hardly ever use 'filial', the word means son-like, "from Late Latin filialis "of a son or daughter," so you are saying "a son like a son",  or "son of a son," boomerang-speak!